# Calculating mean of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, mean

Hello I'm having issues calculating the mean of in my function, the program compiles however I don't get the intended answer of 64.2 to print out and instead get a random set of integers and characters.

This is not the entirety of the code but only the appropriate variables and functions.

```
        // main function and prototyping would be here
 int size=0;
 float values[]={10.1, 9.2, 7.9, 9.2, 13.0, 12.7, 11.3};


    float mean(float values[], int size)
   {
      float sum = 0;
      float mean = 0;

            for (size = 0; size > 7; size++)
                  {
                    sum += values[size];
                    mean = sum / 7;
                  }

return mean;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is the test `size > 7` there? Expecting your initial value to have an unusually large value of zero? It's likely that you mean `size < 7`, though using arbitrary magic numbers like that is trouble.

What you probably want is:

```
float mean(float* values, int size)
{
  float sum = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
     sum += values[i];

  return sum / size;
}
```

To be more C++ you'd want that signature to be:

```
float mean(const float* values, const size_t size)
```

That way you'd catch any mistakes with modifying those values.

Comment: Oh my! I've flipped the greater than sign, didn't realize. Thank you!

Comment: We all make mistakes like that. I usually read out the code to myself to be sure I'm getting it right, as if explaining it to someone. [Rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) works!

Answer (score 1):

Change your loop like so:

```
for (size = 0; size < 7; size++)
{
    sum += values[size];
}
mean = sum / 7;
```

1. Your terminating condition for `for` loop isn't right.
2. Move the `mean` out of for loop.

Comment: Glad could help! For `for` and `while` loop, the terminating condition is most imp thing and that's the 1st place you should always look into in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (size = 0; size > 7; size++)
```

Since size is initialized as 0, and it is incremented by 1, it becomes 1 at the end of the first iteration and fails the test (it is not > 7). Thus, it immediately exits the loop.

Secondly, you calculate mean inside the loop when you should calculate it after the loop is complete. Theoretically, you should get a correct value since you redo it as the mean of the sums to that point in the loop, but it is a waste of time. You also wipe out size by redefining it.

```
float mean(float values[], int size)
{
  float sum = 0;
  float mymean = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
       sum += values[i];
    }
  mymean = sum / size;

  return mymean;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, especially in pointing out the inefficiency.

Comment: @user3432946 Note that I make sure that the function name is not used as a variable name. While the C++ compiler could handle it, it is a bad habit as there are languages (and possibly some C++ compilers) that would be thrown off by that. Even if it works (such as using a global name inside a local scope) it is better to act as if it were an error. Someday you will be in a situation where it is an error.